# couldn't find file 'jquery-ui' after installing correct gem files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

This is my gemfile

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

    gem 'jquery-rails'


    gem 'pg'

    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
        gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    group :development, :test do
      gem "rails-erd"
      gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', '~> 0.6.1'
      gem 'debugger'
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.12.0'
      gem 'annotate'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails'
      gem 'shoulda-matchers'
      gem 'simplecov', :require => false
      gem 'simplecov-rcov', :require => false
      gem 'pry'
      gem "guard-rspec"
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'mocha', '0.13.3'
    end

    group :test do
      gem "webmock"
    end

    gem 'debugger' # This gem works with ruby 1.9.3 it wraps these other things
    gem 'savon', "~> 1.2.0"
    gem 'airbrake'
    gem 'aasm'
    gem 'paranoia'
    gem 'acts_as_tree'
    gem 'will_paginate'
    gem 'translate-rails3'
    gem 'wicked_pdf'
    gem 'activemerchant'
    gem 'libxml-ruby'
    gem 'libxslt-ruby'
    gem 'ruby-xslt'
    gem 'exception_notification', :require => 'exception_notifier'
    gem "uuidtools", "~> 2.1.3"
    gem "ruby-filemagic"
    gem "rmagick", :require => false
    gem "rubyzip"
    gem "spreadsheet"
    gem "multi_json"
    gem "multi_xml"
    gem "httparty"
    gem "paperclip", :git => "http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"

    #FormBuilder backwards compatibility
    gem "dynamic_form"
    gem "prototype-rails"

    gem "formtastic"

    gem "net-ssh"
    gem "net-scp"

    # CODEREVIEW, we have to remove all the legacy stuff as soon as is possible  
    gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', '0.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git'
    gem 'simple_cms', :git => 'git://github.com/gianu/simple_cms.git', :branch => "tinymce_gem"  #:path => '~/play/simple_cms'
    gem 'acts_as_versioned', :git => 'git://github.com/gianu/acts_as_versioned.git'
    gem "airbrake"
```

and these are the gems in the gemset that um using

```
                aasm (3.0.20, 3.0.19, 3.0.13)
                actionmailer (3.2.13, 3.2.8)
                actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
                active_utils (2.0.0, 1.0.5)
                activemerchant (1.34.0, 1.28.0)
                activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.8)
                activerecord (3.2.13, 3.2.8)
                activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.8)
                activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
                acts_as_tree (1.4.0, 1.1.0)
                addressable (2.3.5, 2.3.3)
                airbrake (3.1.12, 3.1.6)
                akami (1.2.0)
                annotate (2.5.0)
                arel (3.0.2)
                atomic (1.1.10)
                builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
                bundler (1.3.5)
                bundler-unload (1.0.1)
                choice (0.1.6)
                climate_control (0.0.3)
                cocaine (0.5.1)
                coderay (1.0.9, 1.0.8)
                coffee-rails (3.2.2)
                coffee-script (2.2.0)
                coffee-script-source (1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.4.0)
                columnize (0.3.6)
                connection_pool (0.9.2)
                crack (0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.2)
                debugger (1.6.1, 1.6.0)
                debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
                debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3, 1.2.2)
                diff-lcs (1.1.3)
                dynamic_form (1.1.4)
                erubis (2.7.0)
                eventmachine (1.0.0)
                exception_notification (4.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
                execjs (1.4.0)
                factory_girl (4.2.0, 4.1.0)
                factory_girl_rails (4.2.1, 4.1.0)
                faraday (0.8.4)
                faraday_middleware (0.8.8)
                ffi (1.9.0)
                formatador (0.2.4)
                formtastic (2.2.1)
                girl_friday (0.10.0)
                guard (1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.5.0)
                guard-rspec (2.5.4, 1.2.1)
                gyoku (0.4.6)
                hashie (1.2.0)
                hike (1.2.3)
                http_parser.rb (0.5.3)
                httparty (0.11.0, 0.10.2)
                httpi (1.1.1)
                i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
                journey (1.0.4)
                jquery-rails (3.0.4)
                json (1.8.0)
                libxml-ruby (2.7.0, 2.6.0, 2.3.3)
                libxslt-ruby (1.1.0, 1.0.9)
                listen (1.2.2, 0.5.3)
                lumberjack (1.0.4, 1.0.2)
                mail (2.5.4, 2.4.4)
                metaclass (0.0.1)
                method_source (0.8.2, 0.8.1)
                mime-types (1.23)
                mini_portile (0.5.1, 0.5.0)
                minitest (4.7.5)
                mocha (0.14.0, 0.13.3)
                money (5.1.1, 5.0.0)
                multi_json (1.7.8, 1.7.7, 1.7.6)
                multi_xml (0.5.5, 0.5.4, 0.5.3)
                multipart-post (1.1.5)
                net-scp (1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.0.4)
                net-ssh (2.6.8, 2.6.7, 2.6.2)
                nokogiri (1.6.0, 1.5.5)
                nori (1.1.5, 1.1.4)
                paperclip (3.4.2)
                paranoia (1.3.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0)
                pg (0.16.0, 0.15.1, 0.14.1)
                polyglot (0.3.3)
                prototype-rails (3.2.1)
                pry (0.9.12.2, 0.9.10)
                rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
                rack-cache (1.2)
                rack-ssl (1.3.3)
                rack-test (0.6.2)
                rails (3.2.13)
                rails-dev-tweaks (0.6.1)
                rails-erd (1.1.0)
                railties (3.2.13, 3.2.8)
                rake (10.1.0, 10.0.4)
                rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
                rb-inotify (0.9.0)
                rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
                rdoc (3.12.2)
                responds_to_parent (1.1.0)
                rmagick (2.13.2, 2.13.1)
                rspec (2.12.0, 2.10.0)
                rspec-core (2.12.2, 2.10.1)
                rspec-expectations (2.12.1, 2.10.0)
                rspec-mocks (2.12.2, 2.10.1)
                rspec-rails (2.12.0, 2.10.0)
                ruby-filemagic (0.4.2)
                ruby-graphviz (1.0.9)
                ruby-ole (1.2.11.7, 1.2.11.4)
                ruby-xslt (0.9.9)
                rubygems-bundler (1.2.1)
                rubyzip (0.9.9)
                rvm (1.11.3.8)
                safe_yaml (0.9.5, 0.9.4, 0.9.3)
                sass (3.2.10, 3.2.9, 3.2.1)
                sass-rails (3.2.6, 3.2.5)
                savon (1.2.0)
                shoulda-matchers (2.2.0, 1.4.1)
                simple_oauth (0.1.9)
                simplecov (0.7.1)
                simplecov-html (0.7.1)
                simplecov-rcov (0.2.3)
                slop (3.4.6, 3.4.5, 3.3.3)
                spreadsheet (0.8.8, 0.8.7, 0.8.5, 0.7.4)
                sprockets (2.2.2, 2.1.3)
                thor (0.18.1)
                thread_safe (0.1.0)
                tilt (1.4.1)
                tinder (1.9.1)
                tinymce-rails (4.0.2, 4.0.1, 4.0, 3.5.8)
                translate-rails3 (0.2.3)
                treetop (1.4.14)
                twitter-stream (0.1.16)
                tzinfo (0.3.37)
                uglifier (2.1.2, 2.1.1, 1.3.0)
                uuidtools (2.1.4, 2.1.3)
                wasabi (2.5.1)
                webmock (1.13.0, 1.12.3, 1.11.0)
                wicked_pdf (0.9.6, 0.7.9)
                will_paginate (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
                ya2yaml (0.31)
```

and once i run the rails s it gives me

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound 
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
```

Can anyone help? I have gone through every solution mentioned in stackoverflow but it didnt helped me out . Thank you  inadvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue . I have used jquery-rails (2.1.3) then it worked perfectly . Its not essectial to install jquery-ui gem

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have `jquery-ui-rails` gem in your Gemfile.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

After adding `jquery-ui-rails`, execute the `bundle` command to install it.

Then you also need to include `js` and `css` to you `application.js` and `application.css`.

app/assets/javsacripts/application.js

```
//=require jquery-ui
```

and add the following to your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*=require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

You can also include individual javascript and stylesheet based on the plugins you use, for example if you only need datepicker then you could modify your application.js and application.css as follows:

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

Comment: Did you restart the rails server after doing `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes I did restart the server

Comment: Make sure `jquery-ui-rails` is installed issuing `bundle show jquery-ui-rails`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing:

`//= require jquery.ui.datepicker`

with:

`//= require jquery-ui/datepicker`

worked for me.